# How to get the name of the component that's extending mine in ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion, components, cfc

Let's say I have the following component called ***Base***:

```
<cfcomponent output="false">

    <cffunction name="init" access="public" returntype="Any" output="false">
        <cfset variables.metadata = getmetadata(this)>
        <cfreturn this>
    </cffunction>

    <cffunction name="getmeta" access="public" returntype="Any" output="false">
        <cfreturn variables.metadata>
    </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

and I want to extend base in another component called ***Admin***:

```
<cfcomponent output="false" extends="Base">
</cfcomponent>
```

Now within my application if I do the following when creating the object:

```
<cfset obj = createobject("component", "Admin").init()>
<cfdump var="#obj.getmeta()#">
```

The metadata I get back tells me that the name of the component is ***Admin*** and it's extending my ***Base*** component. That's all good, but I don't want to have to call the ***init()*** method explicitly when creating the object.

I would be nice if I could do something like this in my ***Base*** component:

```
<cfcomponent output="false">

    <cfset init()>

    <cffunction name="init" access="public" returntype="Any" output="false">
        <cfset variables.metadata = getmetadata(this)>
        <cfreturn this>
    </cffunction>

    <cffunction name="getmeta" access="public" returntype="Any" output="false">
        <cfreturn variables.metadata>
    </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

However then the metadata returned by the getmeta() method telling me that the component name is ***Base*** even though it's still being extended. Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you don't want to call init in each extending cfc?

```
<cfcomponent output="false" extends="Base">
    <cfset super.init()>

</cfcomponent>
```

That seems to populate the metadata like you want.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you are after, but ColdFusion 8 added the getComponentMetaData() function that instead of requiring an instantiated CFC, takes a dot notation path to the CFC. You should be able to get the path from Admin which you can pass to getComponentMetaData() without calling the init() on Base.

[ColdFusion LiveDoc: getComponentMetaData()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/functions_e-g_33.html#5190523)

Answer (score 1):

6 years old, but I'll give the real answer...

Given Base.cfc:

```
component{
    public function foo(){
        return 'base';
    }
}
```

And Child.cfc:

```
component extends="Base"{
    public function foo(){
        return 'child';
    }
}
```

To find out what component Child extends, just do this:

```
<cfscript>
child = createObject( "component", "Child" );
writeDump( getMetaData(child).extends.name );
</cfscript>
```